# Agrupar JSON usando reduce() do javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Utilizei o reduce para fazer o agrupamento do meu Json, porém preciso agrupar por mais de 1 parâmetro, para fazer o group corretamente.

*Segue a função utilizada:*

```
>     this.totalSpecific = obj.reduce(function (acumulador, valor) {
>           var indice = acumulador.map((o) => o.janela).indexOf(valor.janela);
>           if (indice == -1) {
>             acumulador.push(valor);
>           } else {
>             acumulador[indice].qtd += valor.qtd;
>           }
>           return acumulador;
>         }, []);
```

*Usando essa função tenho o seguinte retorno:*

```
[{"janela":"08","qtd":2342,"port":0},
 {"janela":"20","qtd":1546,"port":0}]
```

**Exemplo** *de retorno que necessito:*

```
[{"janela":"08","qtd":1142,"port":0},
 {"janela":"08","qtd":1250,"port":1}
 {"janela":"08","qtd":950,"port":2}
 {"janela":"20","qtd":1046,"port":0},
 {"janela":"20","qtd":450,"port":1},
 {"janela":"20","qtd":50,"port":2}]
```

*Segue Json usado:*

```
let obj =   [{
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 11,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 63,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 2,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 129,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 6,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 33,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 53,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 77,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 589,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 4,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 13,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 18,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 131,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 36,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 24,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 109,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 11,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 40,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 6,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 43,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 351,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 68,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 21,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 84,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 340,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 6,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 9,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 2,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 6,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 2,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "08        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 150,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 4,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 12,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 38,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 188,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 247,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 9,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 11,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 2,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 22,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 155,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 23,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 15,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 96,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 81,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 12,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 75,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 169,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 9,
                "port": 0
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 31,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 5,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 31,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 1
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 4,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 38,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 18,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 7,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 1,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 61,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 3,
                "port": 2
              },
              {
                "janela": "20        ",
                "qtd": 6,
                "port": 2
              }
            ]
```

Comment: Você quer somar o campo `qtd` para `janela` e `port` iguais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj.reduce((acc,currentValue) => {
serviceSumItem = acc.find(o => o.janela === currentValue.janela && o.port === currentValue.port);
serviceSumItem ? serviceSumItem.qtd += currentValue.qtd :  acc.push(currentValue);
return acc;
```

},[])

Essa estrutura não me parece estar corretamente modelada, mas o código acima deve funcionar.